# Same class name for two packages

Tags: flutter

I import `google_maps_flutter` and `augmented_reality_plugin_wikitude`

Both uses the same name class as `CameraPosition`.

I don't use `CameraPostion` class for `google_maps_futter`.

How can I avoid name comflict??

```
lib/main.dart:6:1: Error: 'CameraPosition' is imported from both 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' and 'package:augmented_reality_plugin_wikitude/startupConfiguration.dart'.
import 'package:augmented_reality_plugin_wikitude/startupConfiguration.dart'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **[as](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators)** keyword to reference all the respective variables and methods.

For Ex:

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' as cp1;
import 'package:augmented_reality_plugin_wikitude/startupConfiguration.dart' as cp2;
```

Now, to use CameraPosition or other methods from google_maps_flutter you can use **"cp1"** reference like cp1.method1().

Similarly, to use CameraPosition or other methods from augmented_reality_plugin you can use **"cp2"** reference like cp2.method1().

> The as keyword's main purpose are typecast and to specify the library prefixes. So this is the best solution for your use case.

Answer (score 6):

Hide `CameraPosition` from `google_maps_flutter` while importing

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' hide CameraPosition;
```

Comment: for me it was `File`, which were available in both  packages those are `dart:html` and  `dart:io`, where I need it from `dart:io` hence hide the `import 'dart:html' hide File` yup, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways you could fix this:

1. Specify an import prefix like `import '../../something.dart' as st;`

   Then use it something like this: `st.ImportedClass some = st.ImportedClass();`
   It also supports `import '../../something.dart' show thisthing hide thatthing;`
2. Absolute imports
   `import 'package:my_lib/shared/something.dart`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid such conflicts by importing one of them in another name. So while importing one of two, let's say you can import google_maps as

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' as gmaps;
```

So CameraPosition from google maps plugin will be accessed using gmaps.CameraPosition, so there will no longer be any conflicts.